# Tensorflow: DecodeJpeg method gives different pixel values on desktop and mobile for the same image

Tags: android, tensorflow, arm, libjpeg

I have used `Tensorflow's` `DecodeJpeg` to read images while training a model. In order to use the same method on an android device, I compiled Tensorflow with Bazel for android with `DecodeJpeg`.

I tried reading the same image on my desktop, which is an `x86_64` machine that runs windows. I ran the `DecodeJpeg` method on an image with default values with `dct_method` set to `''`, `INTEGER_FAST`, `INTEGER_ACCURATE`.

I did the same on an `arm64` device, for the same image. But, the pixel values were significantly different for the same image under the same settings.

For instance, at (100,100,1) the value on the desktop is `213`, while it is `204` on `arm64`.

How can I make sure that the pixel values are the same across these two devices?[![This is the image I have used][1]][1]

**Update:**
On Gimp at `(100,100)` the pixel values are `(179,203,190)`

For `dct_method` set to `INTEGER_FAST`, the value at `(100,100)` on x86_64 is `(171, 213, 165)`, on arm it is `(180, 204, 191)`

For `dct_method` set to `INTEGER_ACCURATE`, the value at `(100,100)` on x86_64 is `(170, 212, 164)`, on arm it is `(179, 203, 190)`

It is `(170, 212, 164)` with `PIL`, which is what I get with `cv2.imread` as well.

Answer (score 0):

According to [tensorflow image decode_jpeg documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/decode_jpeg)
I expect that it may be relative to some attribute when you decode the jpeg.
Most probably the `channels` attribute and/or the `ratio` attribute and/or the `fancy_upscaling` attr.

Both of them can change the value of the pixel...

Concerning the `channels`:

> The attr channels indicate the desired number of color channels for the decoded image.
>
> Accepted values are:
>
> ```
> 0: Use the number of channels in the JPEG-encoded image.
> 1: output a grayscale image.
> 3: output an RGB image.
> ```

Concerning the `ratio`:

> The attr ratio allows downscaling the image by an integer factor during decoding. Allowed values are 1, 2, 4, and 8. This is much faster than downscaling the image later.

Concerning the `fancy_upscaling`:

> fancy_upscaling: An optional bool. Defaults to True. If true use a slower but nicer upscaling of the chroma planes (yuv420/422 only).

---

Please note that you may also have **to explicitly specify a value for the `dct_method`** because according to [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/decode_jpeg) if you don't specify a value it will use **a system-specific default**.

And in my opinion, it (*the dct_method empty arg*) is the most probable reason which explains why you don't have the same result on x86_64 and ARM.

> the internal jpeg library changes to a version that does not have that
> specific option

Comment: Please take a look at the update to the question. I have included values for different `dct` methods. On both x86_64 and arm, I'm using default values for `ratio` and `fancy_upscaling`, and `channels` is set to `3`.